# iisnode not restarting/updating Node.js on file changes

Tags: node.js, iis, iisnode

Using iisnode and whenever I change a `.js` or `.hbs (handlebars)` file the Node.js app does not restart to update the changes. But if I change my `web.config` file then it does update.

This is basically what I have in my `web.config` file. I also updated the iisnode.yml file to be the same (but I don't understand why I can't just have the web.config file do everything... why have iisnode.yml?)

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
....
<!-- rewrite rules and handler appears here --->

<iisnode
              node_env="%node_env%"
              nodeProcessCountPerApplication="1"
              maxConcurrentRequestsPerProcess="1024"
              maxNamedPipeConnectionRetry="100"
              namedPipeConnectionRetryDelay="250"
              maxNamedPipeConnectionPoolSize="512"
              maxNamedPipePooledConnectionAge="30000"
              asyncCompletionThreadCount="0"
              initialRequestBufferSize="4096"
              maxRequestBufferSize="65536"
              watchedFiles="*;*.hbs;web.config;*.js" <!-- told it to watch everything -->
              uncFileChangesPollingInterval="5"      <!--- very low polling interval -->
              gracefulShutdownTimeout="60000"
              loggingEnabled="true"
              logDirectory="iisnode"
              debuggingEnabled="true"
              debugHeaderEnabled="false"
              debuggerPortRange="5058-6058"
              debuggerPathSegment="debug"
              maxLogFileSizeInKB="128"
              maxTotalLogFileSizeInKB="1024"
              maxLogFiles="20"
              devErrorsEnabled="true"
              flushResponse="false"
              enableXFF="false"
              promoteServerVars=""
              configOverrides="iisnode.yml"
             />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Why does iisnode only refresh the node.js server when I update `web.config` and not any other file?

Comment: It seems that iisnode element from Web.config that will recylce the site whenever the Web.config changes or any .js files in the top level folder of the app. Do you modify the top level folder's js?

Comment: I didn't modify any top-level .js files. Good point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Brando's comment I fixed it by doing this:

`watchedFiles="*.js;*.hbs;web.config;routes\*;views\*;controllers\*;models\*"`

That line specifies which folders, other than the root folder, that you want iisnode to watch files for changes.

Comment: that's right, wildcards are allowed only for files, so you need to specify each folder to watch